# Transforming a Hlist[F[A]] into F[B] where case class B has aligned types with A

Tags: scala, typeclass, shapeless, fixed-width, scodec

*Note: I am learning shapeless, so please ask for clarification if I miss any details.*

### Background:

I am building an encoding/decoding solution for fixed-length format while practising Shapeless. The idea is that each `case class` would have its own *encoder/decoder* defined as an `HList` aligned with its properties.

Even if two classes share the same properties, their encoding may be different. The description for each field would contain some(4) values. But this is not important in the problem.

### Problem:

**The full code is available here: https://github.com/atais/Fixed-Length/blob/03b395947a6b00e548ea1e76a9660e471f136565/src/main/scala/test/Main.scala**

I declare a sample case class and its encoder:

```
case class Employee(name: String, number: Int, manager: Boolean)

object Employee {
  implicit val employeeEncoder =
    FLEncoder.fixed((s: String) => s) ::
    FLEncoder.fixed((s: String) => s) ::
    FLEncoder.fixed((s: Int) => s.toString) ::
    FLEncoder.fixed((s: Boolean) => s.toString) ::
      HNil
}
```

so the type of my `employeeEncoder` is a beautiful:

```
::[FLEncoder[String], ::[FLEncoder[String], ::[FLEncoder[Int], ::[FLEncoder[Boolean], HNil]]]]
```

Now, encoder `implicitly` is looking for an `FLEncoder[Employee]`, which I hope could be the above implementation.

I have used this solution to combine TypeClasses for tuples:

- [Composing typeclasses for tuples in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321482/composing-typeclasses-for-tuples-in-scala)
- https://www.scala-exercises.org/shapeless/auto_typeclass_derivation

But I am getting:

```
Error:(69, 17) could not find implicit value for parameter enc: test.FLEncoder[test.Employee]
  println(encode(example))
```

If I declare those encoders separately, they are working fine

```
implicit val a = fixed((s: String) => s)
implicit val b = fixed((s: Int) => s.toString)
implicit val c = fixed((s: Boolean) => s.toString)
```

### Question:

So basically, how to use `Shapeless` so it would know that this `Hlist` is an encoder type for an aligned `case class`?

---

**A Similar problem is solved in scodec**. If you check a demo here:
https://github.com/atais/Fixed-Length/blob/03b395947a6b00e548ea1e76a9660e471f136565/src/main/scala/test/Fixed.scala

you are able to do such transformation:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

val pc: Codec[shapeless.::[String, shapeless.::[Int, HNil]]] = (("name" | fixed(10, '_')) :: ("age" | fixed(6, '0').narrow[Int](strToInt, _.toString)))

val personCodec: Codec[Person] = pc.as[Person]
```

But I do not know how could I use [TransformSyntax.as](http://scodec.org/api/scodec-core/1.10.3/#scodec.package$$TransformSyntax) in my case.

Comment: Could you give us the trait `FLEncoder[T]`, to better understand what you're trying to achieve? In the meantime, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44358332/shapeless-not-working-in-generic-context, where a full example is given (part of which in my solution).

Comment: the encoder is eclosed on the GitHub in `Main.scala`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to give a way to tell the compiler that your list of `FLEncoder` can be converted to a `FLEncoder` of list. Since we are on the type level, this can be done with a typeclass:

```
trait ListOfEncoder[L <: HList] {
  type Inside <: HList
  def merge(l: L): FLEncoder[Inside]
}

object ListOfEncoder {
  type Aux[L <: HList, I <: HList] = ListOfEncoder[L] { type Inside = I }

  implicit val hnil: Aux[HNil, HNil] = new ListOfEncoder[HNil] {
    type Inside = HNil
    def merge(l: HNil) = FLEncoder.fixed(_ => "")
  }

  implicit def hcons[H, T <: HList](implicit T: ListOfEncoder[T]): Aux[FLEncoder[H] :: T, H :: T.Inside] = new ListOfEncoder[FLEncoder[H] :: T] {
    type Inside = H :: T.Inside
    def merge(l: FLEncoder[H] :: T): FLEncoder[H :: T.Inside] =
      FLEncoder.fixed((ht: H :: T.Inside) => l.head.encode(ht.head) + T.merge(l.tail).encode(ht.tail))
  }
}
```

Now, in your `FLEncoder object, add this implicit class:

```
implicit class EncoderAsGeneric[L <: HList, I <: HList](l: L)(implicit L: ListOfEncoder.Aux[L, I]) {
  def as[E](implicit gen: Generic.Aux[E, I]) = 
    FLEncoder.fixed((e: E) => L.merge(l).encode(gen.to(e))
}
```

This will allow you to define

```
implicit val employeeEncoder = (fixed((s: String) => s) ::
  fixed((s: String) => s) ::
  fixed((s: Int) => s.toString) ::
  fixed((s: Boolean) => s.toString) ::
    HNil).as[Employee]
```

And now, all the implicits should be in scope for your `Main` as it is.

By the way, since you define your FLEncoder with `HList`, there is no need for `ProductTypeClassCompanion` anymore, since this is only for inference from base cases.

Comment: I added your object and imported the implicits but I still get the same error.
Could you fork my `Main.scala` and give a working solution?

Comment: What you still miss is the generic conversion (from your `HList` to `Employee`). I'll PR you and put the updated answer here.

Comment: Do you know why the compiler did not know that the Hlist i am producing is not equal to the one Shapeless would create? Why it did not find it as an implicit value?

Comment: shapeless never produces a `F[A] :: F[B] :: HNil`, but a `F[A :: B :: HNil]` which are quite different when you think about it.